# Getting database information in Laravel Blade Template with Inner Join

Tags: database-design, data-binding, laravel, laravel-4

This question has to do with Laravel, but also general database design as well since I am new to both.

I have made a database that is like this:

people

- id
- firstname
- lastname
- **address**
- yadayada

address

- **id**
- line1
- city
- state
- zip
- yadayada

There is a "people" and it can have an address. I have split this way because company (another section of this app) will also have addresses, as well as meeting place and POI will have an address too. I am building a CRM type system. Now, I need to retrieve the information from the database. But there is a problem because there are 2 columns named "id".

My Inner Join is as follows. And it works:
            $people = DB::table('people')
                ->join('address', 'address.id', '=', 'people.address')
                ->get();

```
        return View::make('people.index')
            ->with('people', $people);
```

But when I go to my Laravel Blade template everything works fine the Inner Join is successful and the data is displayed, but I need to create a Resourceful Controller link which links to the ID so that it can be viewed on its own page:

```
        @foreach ($people as $people)
            <li>
                <a href="{{ URL::to('people/' . $people->id) }}" class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="" />
                </a>
                <div class="caption">
                    <p>
                        {{ $people->firstname }}<br />
                        {{ $people->lastname }}<br />
                        {{ $people->line1 }}<br />
                        {{ $people->city }}<br /><br />

</p>
            </li>
        @endforeach
```

Which returns very crazy results because it doesn't know which "id" to use. (It is using the address table's id with weird results)

1. Is there a way to specify a table name in Laravel? (This does not work):

   ```
       <a href="{{ URL::to('people/' . $people->people.id) }}" class="thumbnail">
           <img src="" />
       </a>
   ```
2. Or is it general good database practice not to use "id" in two different tables? in which case I could rename and the problem would be fixed

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just a side note: Eloquent will make your life much easier here.

Comment: @Mike-Anthony I'm very new to Laravel, but I think I am using eloquent. Here is my controller 'code'   $people = DB::table('people')
   ->join('address', 'address.address_id', '=', 'people.address')
            ->get();
   
  return View::make('people.index')
   ->with('people', $people); '/code'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always rename the id fields, but that is not necessary. You can specify your columns by using a SELECT query. For example, SELECT address.id as address_id, people.id as people_id. The downside to this method is you'll need to specify every column name.

Comment: I ended up looking at some other resources and they suggested that I have two fields: address_id mapped to the field address and people_id mapped to the field people. A little annoying but I think better for database design.

Answer (score 1):

For what I can see in the DB design and join clause, `address` column of `people` table (`people.address`) holds the ID of the `address` table.

If so, you can use `people.address` in your Blade view, like this:

```
            <a href="{{ URL::to('people/' . $people->address) }}" class="thumbnail">
```

Also, might be better to use `leftJoin` in this case:

```
 $people = DB::table('people') ->leftJoin('address', 'address.id', '=', 'people.address') ->get();
```

Comment: this did not work. But I ended up renaming the columns so that I could use "address_id" mapped to an "address" column.

I did not try a left join although it might be better. I will have to look into the joins a bit -the scary part of MySQL for me since I don't have a solid grasp on them yet.

Comment: You can take a look at this http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html